# Anyone ever done a mass delete of contacts without a channel?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a list here but I am paranoid about deleting these contacts with NO channel because it might have a ripple effect.

Looking at data designer there is alot of connections and I am just a little worried - anyone here ever done a mass contacts delete?

I did one recently but my contacts shot up 10,000 over the week - is this normal? O_O

Is there a way to find out where they are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

This could be contacts or leads who did not receive any communications yet. Did the contacts get synchronized again from Salesforce or other source? Did you put any filters at data sources so they are not synced right back after deletion? You could write SQL Query to find out where the id's are from.

Comment: I was told that was not possible but could you paste an example of a query - this would be very helpful :)!  I deleted leads and some came back?  

Overall though mass deleting contacts without a channel is wont result in anything catastrophic will it?